# Error when trying to install firebase with NPM

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I am trying to (re)install Firebase, however, when I run `sudo npm install -g firebase-tools` the following error shows up:

[image]

I have no idea what is wrong, it used to work well a few month ago.

Answer (score 5):

**You try running**

```
npm cache clean
```

**and then trying to install again.**

> *If the error is not lost try below*

**Have you tried installing homebridge with the `--unsafe-perm` option?**

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm homebridge
```

If npm detects it is running as root it drops to a non-privileged user which then doesn't have permissions to write to /root/.node-gyp. The --unsafe-perm option stops it from changing user.

nvm doesn't have this problem when not using sudo because it stores everything under the current users' home directory.

Comment: Thank you for your advise, unfortunately none of these worked, the same error popped up. I ended up by completely reinstalling Ubuntu and it works fine now. Sorry for not answering sooner.

Comment: Welcome but No no problem